# How to add custom headers in Next.js 13 API response

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to add custom header in Next.js 13 api response.

Next.js lower version, it allows as ,

```
 response.setHeader( 'Content-Disposition', `...`);
      response.setHeader('Content-Type', '...');
```

Same code i tried in Next.js 13, it shows ERROR AS  response.setHeader is not a function .

I tried inside the api routes file. (Next.js 13)

```
export const GET = async (request: NextApiRequest,response:NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
     ..........
     
      response.setHeader( 'Content-Disposition', `.....`);
      response.setHeader('Content-Type', '....');
      
     .....
     
  } catch (error) {
     ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the only documentation I could find for the `res.setHeader` method is [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#setting-cookies).

This works in Next.js 13

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

one option to fix is to create a new ResponseHeader

according to [NextJs Docu](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#setting-headers)

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  requestHeaders.set('x-hello-from-middleware1', 'hello')
 
  // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // New request headers
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  })
 
  // Set a new response header `x-hello-from-middleware2`
  response.headers.set('x-hello-from-middleware2', 'hello')
  return response
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, i have updated my code also another way to pass custom headers

Answer (score 0):

Updated the response as follow, It works for me

```
const res = new NextResponse(stream, {
      status: 200,
      headers: new Headers({
          "content-disposition":`attachment; filename="${fileName}"` ,
          "content-type":  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 
      })
```